# Why is one graph reversed under convolution?

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), it is said that a convolution function "is defined as the integral of the product of the two functions after one is **reversed** and shifted." The bold is added by me, and shows where my question lies. Why is it reversed?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-convolution/.

Comment: @Moo That helped a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Consider a similar problem with sequences.  If
$$
A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n,\qquad B = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n,
$$
then
$$
AB = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n
$$
where $c_n$ is the convolution
$$
c_n= \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k}b_{n-k}
$$
where you multiply the sequences, but one is reversed and shifted.

---

For convolution of functions:
For example, of $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform, then
$$
\mathcal F(fg) = \mathcal F{f} * \mathcal F(g)
$$
where $*$ is the convolution, defined as in that wikipedia article.  Same for Laplace transform.

It is true that the pointwise product $fg$ is interesting and useful.  But these uses show that the convolution $f * g$ is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of convolution is that you are integrating $f(s) f(t)$ over all $s,t$ with $s+t = x.$ So, you are looking at all ways of decomposing $x$ as $s+t$.

This is useful eg in probability, where if $S$ and $T$ are independent random variables then $$P(S+T = x) = \sum_{s+t = x} P(S=s) P(T=t),$$ ie a convolution. Similarly, in the continuous case, the probability density function of $S+T$ is $f * g$ (convolution), where $f,g$ are the pdfs of $S,T$.

For example, if you want the chance that you roll two weighted dice $D_1, D_2$ and you want to know the probability they add to $4$, you look at all ways of getting a $4$: roll a $1$ and $3$, $2$ and $2$, or $3$ and $1$. So the chance that you roll a $4$ is $$P(D_1 = 1) \cdot P(D_2 =3) + P(D_1 = 2)\cdot P(D_2 =2) + P(D_1 = 3)\cdot P(D_2 =1).$$

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Thanks, fixed.